# Creating a view (virtual table) which display colums with particular requirements

Tags: sql, oracle, view, count, where-clause

So I`m trying to  make a statistic view which counts various things  like how many users are in table called "PACIENTAS" , how many doctors are in table "GYDYTOJAS" and it works.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "NEW" ("PACIENTU SKAIČIUS DUOMENŲ BAZĖJE", "PACIENTAI    UŽSIREGISTRAVĘ VIZITUI", "LIGONINIU SKAICIUS", "GYDYTOJU SKAIČIUS", "ŠIO MENESIO REGISTRACIJOS")   AS 
   SELECT(
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   PACIENTAS) AS VISIPACIENTAI,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   REGISTRACIJA) AS REGPACIENTAI,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  LIGONINE) AS VISOSLIGONINES,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  GYDYTOJAS) AS VISIGYDYTOJAI,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  REGISTRACIJA)  AS REGISTRACIJA
  FROM dual
  /
```

[Counts how many columns are in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Inn.png)

But I want to count  only  columns that fulfil a specified condition

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "NEW" ("PACIENTU SKAIČIUS DUOMENŲ BAZĖJE", "PACIENTAI   UŽSIREGISTRAVĘ VIZITUI", "LIGONINIU SKAICIUS", "GYDYTOJU SKAIČIUS", "ŠIO MENESIO REGISTRACIJOS") AS  
   SELECT(
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   PACIENTAS) AS VISIPACIENTAI,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   REGISTRACIJA) AS REGPACIENTAI,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  LIGONINE) AS VISOSLIGONINES,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  GYDYTOJAS) AS VISIGYDYTOJAI,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  REGISTRACIJA)  AS REGISTRACIJA
   FROM dual
   WHERE ASMENSKODAS > 10  //ASMENSKODAS is a column from PACIENTAS TABLE
   /
```

When I write this code I get an error

> ORA-00904: "PACIENTAS": invalid identifier

I thinking maybe I need to write my condition in count parentheses but I don't know how, I need ideas because I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "NEW" ("PACIENTU SKAIČIUS DUOMENŲ BAZĖJE", "PACIENTAI   UŽSIREGISTRAVĘ VIZITUI", "LIGONINIU SKAICIUS", "GYDYTOJU SKAIČIUS", "ŠIO MENESIO REGISTRACIJOS") AS  
   SELECT(
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   PACIENTAS WHERE ASMENSKODAS > 10) AS VISIPACIENTAI,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   REGISTRACIJA) AS REGPACIENTAI,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  LIGONINE) AS VISOSLIGONINES,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  GYDYTOJAS) AS VISIGYDYTOJAI,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  REGISTRACIJA)  AS REGISTRACIJA
   FROM dual
     //ASMENSKODAS is a column from PACIENTAS TABLE
   /
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referencing a column from the `PACIENTAS` table (i.e. the `ASMENSKODAS`), it has to be "visible" to the query, so - perhaps you meant to use it as I posted below.

Besides, I'd **strongly** suggest you not to name columns like you did. Never, ever use double quotes in Oracle because you'll have to reference those columns every time exactly like you did while creating the view, paying attention to letter case, (too many) spaces (between words) etc. Name columns in a simple manner; for reporting purposes, name them anyway you want.

```
create or replace view new
  (visipacientai, regpacientai, visosligonines, visigydytojai, registracija)
as
SELECT(
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PACIENTAS
        WHERE ASMENSKODAS > 10
       ) AS VISIPACIENTAI,
       --
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  REGISTRACIJA) AS REGPACIENTAI,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  LIGONINE)     AS VISOSLIGONINES,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  GYDYTOJAS)    AS VISIGYDYTOJAI,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  REGISTRACIJA) AS REGISTRACIJA
FROM dual;
```